# Use Tikz to make a title page with colored sections and positioning text

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I am new to latex and want to create a title page that looks something like this:

[image: Desired title page]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{bgcolor1}{Dandelion!50!White!30!}
\newcommand\myfont[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,line width=30mm]

   \draw [draw=bgcolor1,fill=bgcolor1]
     (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1);

   \node[xshift=.7\paperwidth,yshift=1.8cm,text=NavyBlue,font=\myfont{40}{48}] {Text Text Text Text};

   \node[yshift=.5cm,xshift=-5cm] at (current page.center)
     [text width=20cm,text=MidnightBlue,font=\myfont{50}{60},above right]{Text Text Text Text Text};

   \node[yshift=.5cm,xshift=4cm] at (current page.south west)
     [text width=6cm,text=black,font=\Large,above right]{This is a draft blah blah blah blurb random text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My attempt creates a very crude title page that doesn't look much like this.  Can anyone help guide me to something that looks like the example?

[image]

Comment: (\paperwidth,1) is relative to the origin, which is at the baseline at the left side of the text area (where the tikzpicture is located).  I suspect you want ++(\paperwidth,-1in) or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust that you can take it from here....  This uses tikzpagenodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south)}]
\fill[LightYellow] rectangle(0.5\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[xshift=1in,yshift=2in,right]{\Huge\bfseries Example subsubtitle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]
\fill[LightBlue,yshift=-3in] rectangle(\paperwidth,1.5in);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```