# "Turn to the next page" at the bottom of the page

Tags: header-footer, page

At the bottom right corner of a two-page document, how to put the phrase **Turn to the next page** or similar?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387563/use-tikz-to-make-a-title-page-with-colored-sections-and-positioning-text/387564#387564

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `continue` package.

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{continue}
\renewcommand*{\flagcont}{Turn to the next page}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

this will put `Turn to the next page` at the bottom of odd-numbered pages. For more options read the manual (`> texdoc continue`).

Answer (score 4):

Try using `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Avoid lines in header
\fancyfoot[RO]{Turn to the next page $\rightarrow$} % R means right; O means odd-numbered pages
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

Here I make the phrase in the bottom right corner of the odd-numbered pages only. If you want to have it on the bottom right corner of all pages, simply delete the `O` in the `\fancyfoot[RO]{...}`.

I'm sorry if the images are a bit difficult to see.

Hope this will help.